# PHP Button onclick="this.disabled=true" unset if page refresh

Tags: onclick

I dont want unset **onclick="this.disabled=true"** if page refresh,

code :

```
<button type="button" class="addb btn btn-primary rounded-pill py-2 btn-block" type="submit"  data-voice_sku="'.$row["voice_sku"].'" data-voice_name="'.$row["voice_name"].'" onclick="this.disabled=true">Add to Playlist</button>
```

If page refresh onclick event unset. how to prevent?

Answer (score 1):

I would use localStorage for this. Here is a basic example:

```
<button id="myBtn" type="button" onclick="disable_btn(this);">Add to Playlist</button>


<script>
    // disable the button on page load
    (function() {
        if(window.localStorage.getItem('myBtn') == 'true'){
            document.getElementById('myBtn').disabled=true;
        }
    })();

    // function to disable button when clicked
    function disable_btn(el){
        el.disabled=true;
        window.localStorage.setItem('myBtn', true);
    }

</script>
```

And an example for multiple buttons:

```
<button id="btn1" type="button" onclick="disable_btn(this, 'btn1');">Add to Playlist 1</button>
<button id="btn2" type="button" onclick="disable_btn(this, 'btn2');">Add to Playlist 2</button>
<button id="btn3" type="button" onclick="disable_btn(this, 'btn3');">Add to Playlist 3</button>


<script>
    // disable disabled buttons on page load
    (function() {
        var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
            if(window.localStorage.getItem(buttons[i].id) == 'true'){
                buttons[i].disabled=true;
            }
        }
    })();

    // function to disable button when clicked
    function disable_btn(el, id){
        el.disabled=true;
        window.localStorage.setItem(id, true);
    }

</script>
```

This way, disabled buttons will always stay disabled for that user, unless he clears the browsers cache.

Comment: not working, my button : <button type="button" class="addb btn btn-primary rounded-pill py-2 btn-block" type="submit"  data-voice_sku="'.$row["voice_sku"].'" data-voice_name="'.$row["voice_name"].'" 
     onclick="disable_btn(this);">
     Add to Playlist</button>

Comment: add this to your button: id="myBtn"